# Listening for changes on an HTML date input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, date, input

I have an input like so:

```
<input type="date">
```

Whenever the user changes the date, I set a cookie called 'asOfDate' and refresh the page. The server recomputes the data based on the 'asOfDate'.

The javascript looks like this:

```
$("input").change(function(){
  $.cookie("asofdate", $(this).val());
  window.location.reload();
});
```

The problem is that, the second the user types a single keystroke into the date field, it reloads the page.

I could instead listen for the Enter key being pressed on the date input, which would signify that the user was done editing the date. However, that doesn't capture the case where the user chooses the date from the drop-down calendar UI.

Comment: change event gets triggered only when input loses focus, or to say after input, enter being pressed...

Answer (score -1):

As @Rakesh_Kumar said, you need to catch it when you lose the focus of the input. This can be made by using the blur() function. You code then goes like this:

```
$("input").blur(function(){
  $.cookie("asofdate", $(this).val());
  window.location.reload();
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work because pressing ENTER doesn't make the focus go away.  Clicking the calendar dropdown also doesn't make the focus go away

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$("input").keyup(function(e){
    if(e.which == 13){
        $.cookie("asofdate", $(this).val());
        window.location.reload();   
    }
});
```

Comment: what is the problem brief me?

Comment: your solution doesn't capture the case where they choose the date from the calendar dropdown UI.  I want it to refresh without hitting enter if they choose it from the calendar.